# Toggle .html text on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to build a collase expand function on my website.

I have the following that toggle ths hidden div only im trying to change the 'Expand' text to collapse, and then if clicked again, collapse > expand.

Can anybvody see what im doing wrong?

```
$('.coverage .expand').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.subitems').toggle('slow', function() {
        var togtit = $(this).parent().find('.expand');
        if((togtit).is('Expand')){
            togtit.html('Collapse')
        } else {
            togtit.html('Expand')
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method in wrong way. You may try the following instead:

```
$(this).parent().find(".expand").html(function(i, html) {
    return html === "Expand" ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(togtit.html() == 'Expand'){
     togtit.html('Collapse')
} else {
     togtit.html('Expand')
}
```

Above should work.

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element,
>   or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements
>   matches the given arguments.

[jQuery.is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) should be used to check if element matches selector. It will not test inner content of an element.